# How do I pass more than 60 files into python as arguments (Using a Bat File)(Windows)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, batch-file

So I have a few python scripts which work by dragging text files into a BAT file so they are passed to python as arguments i can iterate through.

This works great but for some weird reason, if I attempt to drag in more than around 60 files, nothing happens and the command window instantly closes.

I'm at a loss for why this happens as it could be a restriction with windows, command prompt or python, but I'm not sure which.

Any Help Appreciated.

Eg. Bat File:

```
@Echo off
python "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Work\Automation\test.py" %*
pause
```

eg. Python Script:

```
for x in range(len(sys.argv) - 1): 
     file = os.path.basename(sys.argv[x + 1])
     [ETC.]
```

## '#'#'#'#'#'#'#'#'#'#'#'#'#'#'#'

Thanks again to "pritaeas" for the solution:

Adjusting my python code to

```
for x in range(len(sys.argv) - 1):
    FILES = os.listdir(sys.argv[x+1])
    for y in range(len(FILES)):
        print(FILES[y])
        [ETC.]
```

and dragging in the directory containing the text files, removes the limit i was experiencing before and allows me to drag in multiple directories.

Comment: Perhaps the total of 8K for the command is exceeded. [See this about the limitation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/830473/command-prompt-cmd-exe-command-line-string-limitation). Not sure about the limit on newer machines.

Comment: Thats seems like the solution, 8K max characters divided by 60 leaves around 130 characters per command which is around what im passing it.

Ill try passing the containing folder and have python iterate through the contained files, hopefully that'll work

Thanks for the help :)